# In R, how do I maintain column names through by and zoo?

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo, names

I have a long-format `data.frame` which I would like to use to construct a wide-format `zoo` series.

The `data.frame` looks like:

```
        Date Label Value
1 2015-03-21     A     1
2 2015-03-22     B     6
3 2015-03-22     A     2
4 2015-03-23     A     7
5 2015-03-23     B     5
...
```

For example:

```
d <- data.frame(
    Date = c(Sys.Date() - 2, Sys.Date() - 1, Sys.Date() -1, Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()), 
    Label = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B"), 
    Value = c(1, 6, 2, 7, 5))
```

My result should be a `zoo` that looks like:

```
           A  B ...
2015-03-21 1 NA ...
2015-03-22 2  6 ...
2015-03-23 7  5 ...
...
```

I have managed to achieve this using:

```
f <- function(x) {

    zoo(x$Value, order.by = x$Date)
}

do.call(merge.zoo, by(d, factor(d$Label), f))
```

where `d` is the `data.frame`.

However, when `d` only contains one `Label`, it drops the column name somewhere:

```
2015-03-21 2015-03-22 2015-03-23 
         1          2          7
```

and `names(d)` gives `NULL`.

How can I maintain the column names, even when the output `zoo` is univariate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `merge.zoo` will drop names for a univariate `zoo` by default.

This behaviour can be overridden by passing `drop = F` to the args list. We can use a partial function application of `merge.zoo` to achieve this when using `do.call`:

```
f <- function(x) {

    zoo(x$Value, order.by = x$Date)
}

s <- do.call(partial(merge.zoo, drop = F), by(d, factor(d$Label), f))
```

or without partial:

```
s <- do.call(merge.zoo, append(by(d, factor(d$Label), f), list(drop = F)))
```

For `d <- d[d$Label == "A", ]` this gives:

```
           A
2015-03-21 1
2015-03-22 2
2015-03-23 7
```

Note that the `pryr` package is required for partial function application.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `split=` argument of `read.zoo` to split on the second column:

```
library(zoo)
read.zoo(d, split = 2)
```

giving:

```
           A  B
2015-03-21 1 NA
2015-03-22 2  6
2015-03-23 7  5
```